# Dynamics CRM OData query filtering on expanded attributes only works if no results come out?

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement to fetch `Price List Item` records which adhere to the following requirements:

1. Filter by a specific PriceList
2. Filter by a specific currency
3. Filter by the `Name` of the related `Product` containing a given string

I got the first two points working no problem, but it feels like expanding doesn't cope well with filtering. I started from a "straight" query on `Product` entity:

```
.../ProductSet?$filter=substringof('sometext', Name)

Equivalent SQL (targeting the corresponding CRM filtered views for clarity):
SELECT * FROM FilteredProduct WHERE ProductNumber LIKE '%sometext%'
```

The above query works, I can tweak it and have no issues. However, if I attempt to move on to `ProductPriceLevel` (thus expanding the relationship with `Product`, which is `product_price_levels`) I end up with this:

```
.../ProductPriceLevelSet?$expand=product_price_levels&$filter=substringof('sometext', product_price_levels/Name)

Equivalent SQL (again, targeting the relevant filtered views):
SELECT * FROM FilteredProductPriceLevel PPL JOIN FilteredProduct P 
    ON PPL.ProductId = P.ProductId WHERE P.ProductNumber LIKE '%sometext%'
```

Which has two different outcomes I see:

- If the `$filter` has no matches, it works fine and returns an empty result set
- If the `$filter` matches something, I get an error

> code:    -2147220970
>
> message: The result selector of the 'Join' operation must return an anonymous type of two properties.

AFAIK that's what happens when you hit a limitation of LINQ-to-CRM regarding using `.Where()` on multiple entities at once... doesn't seem relevant!

What's wrong with my query ?

NOTE: The CRM 2013 I'm using is `On-Premise`, without any update rollup / service pack.

ALSO NOTE: The equivalent SQL, as can be expected, works perfectly

Comment: Can you write the Equivalent SQL statement you're attempting to execute in odata?  I'm a little confused as to how you're attempting to apply the filters and a SQL statement would be much more readable.

Comment: Aye, equivalent SQL against the filtered views added to the question

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CRM OData supports adding a filter on a joined entity.  Try reversing the entity you're actually starting with, and add a path to the referencing entity:

```
ProductSet()?$filter=substringof('sometext',ProductNumber)&$expand=product_price_levels&$select=product_price_levels/*
```

P.S. If you have linqPad, this is the query I used to generate this:

```
from p in ProductSet
where p.ProductNumber.Contains("sometext")
select new { p.product_price_levels }
```