# EntityReference attribute Filter with name in organizationdata services

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am filtering record with **CustomerId/Id** with below link in JavaScript.

`/OpportunitySet?$filter=StatusCode/Value eq 3 and **CustomerId/Id** eq (guid’00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000′)`

I want to filter it with CustomerId/name.

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: This might not be possible, but please post an answer if you solve it. See this answer from Daryl: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25793276/1817350

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already know this but, there is a great solution for building your queries, check this out: https://crmrestbuilder.codeplex.com/

Maybe you could use this to build the query you're looking for.

Cheers